# Generalizing Lucas Sequence with the same properites as the originals

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

I am trying to generalize the following Lucas sequence:

https://oeis.org/A001333

where $A_n$ represents the $n$th term of the sequence:

$A_n$ $=$ $2$$*$$A_{n-1}$ $+$ $A_{n-2}$; $A_1 = 1$, $A_2 = 3$, $A_3 = 7$.

To:

$A_n$ $=$ $h$$*$$A_{n-1}$ $+$ $A_{n-2}$; $A_1 = 1$, $A_2 = d$, $A_3 = d_1$

With the following properties:

If $n$ is prime, then $A_n$ $=$ $1$ $\pmod n$ and every prime dividing $A_n$ $=$ $1$ $\pmod n$.

The $A_n$ sequence is not the same as $(a^n - b^n)/(a - b)$ for some integers $a$ and $b$.

Does anyone know an easy way to find any integers $d$, $d_1$, and $h$ for which these properties will hold.

I hope this does not seem too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I assumed that what you meant was : if $p$ is a prime number dividing $n$, then $A_n = 1\ (\mbox{mod p})$.
I had no idea how to approach the problem, so I did a small program, to test if this is possible for $p=5$. I tested all the combinations possible of $d$,$d_1$ and $h$ modulo $5$, and it failed each time for some $n<500$. 
So, if I understood well your question, there are no such integers.